# How to update database using arrays?

Tags: php, jquery, mysql

```
<div data-id=1448 class='item folder'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div data-id=1393 class='item folder'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div data-id=1441 class='item folder'>lorem ipsum</div>
<div data-id=1442 class='item folder'>lorem ipsum</div>
```

**js**

```
$('#mpsave').click(function(){
    var ids = [];
    var indexes = [];
    $('.folder').each(function(){
        ids.push($(this).data('id'));
        indexes.push($(this).index());
    });
    console.log(ids);  // works well
    console.log(indexes);  // works well

$.ajax({
    url: 'target.php',
    type: 'post',
    data: {'ids' : ids, 'indexes' : indexes},
    success: function(data){
        console.log(data); // works well
    }
});
});
```

**target.php**

```
extract($_POST);

print_r($ids);
print_r($indexes);
```

So, arrays are on php side. Now, I need to update database this way:
- for each `ids` element find the corresponding row
- update the row (column `inde`) with value of parallel `indexes` element.

Something like this:

```
try {
$stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE folders SET inde = :inde WHERE id = :id");
$stmt->execute(array(
    ":id" => $ids-element,
    ":inde" => $indexes-element
));
}
catch(PDOException $e) {
echo $e->getMessage();
}
```

Any help?

Comment: Why or what isn't working here?

Comment: @MeesKluivers, how to update database using arrays elements? Please notice ` ":id" => $ids-element,` and `":inde" => $indexes-element`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you even use hyphens in php variable names? Try:

```
    for ($i = 0; $i <= count($ids); $i++){
            try {
                $stmt = $db->prepare("UPDATE folders SET inde = ? WHERE id = ?");
                $stmt->bind_param("ii",$ids[i],$indexes[i]);
                $stmt->execute();
            }
            catch(PDOException $e) {
                echo $e->getMessage();
            }
     }
```

http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli.quickstart.prepared-statements.php
http://php.net/manual/en/mysqli-stmt.bind-param.php

Comment: Thanks a lot, I will test it later, pls.